# LINQ request

Tags: c#, linq

How to do this?

```
int[] mas={1,2,3,4,...,n}

public var method1(mas)
{
var d = from i in Object where i.number==mas[0] || i.number==mas[1] || i.number==mas[2]|| ... || i.number==mas[n] select i;
return d;
}
```

Comment: It's not the most well written question but it's pretty obvious what he is trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to do something like this

```
var d = From i in Object
        From n in mas
        Where n == i.Number
        Select i;
return d;
```

Actually now that I think about that, that is going to return to you a list of i for every match.

You probably were looking for something more like

```
   //create a list for the items that match the criteria
    List<ObjectToGet> d = new List<ObjectToGet>;

    //Loop over each item in your Object
    foreach(ObjectToGet objectItem in Object){
        //If the item contains any match add it to the list
        if((From n in mas Where n == d.Number Select n).Any){
            d.Add(objectItem);
        }
    }

    return d;
```

There's probably a way to write this in pure LINQ but this is conceptually what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `mas` into [HashSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb397727%28v=vs.140%29) by using [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.-ctor?view=net-5.0) and use [Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.contains?view=net-5.0)

Check this article as inroduction: [Introducing HashSet (Kim Hamilton)](https://web.archive.org/web/20151118035648/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/bclteam/archive/2006/11/09/introducing-hashset-t-kim-hamilton.aspx)

So you'll end with something like that:

```
 int[] mas={1,2,3,4,...,n};
 var set = new HashSet<int>(mas); // or you can init set with proper value without array

 public var method1(mas)
 {
    var d = from i in Object where set.Contains(i.number) select i;
    return d;
 }
```

Pure LINQ solution is good too (@msarchet) when you have small enough source array.